# Во всех полях помеченных @Version null при записи в БД

Tags: java, spring, jpa, envers

В проекте использую hibernate-envers+jpa для получения истории изменений сущности, например такой

```
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "User", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "prKey"})})
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "PR_KEY", unique = true)
    private String prKey;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 100, unique = false)
    private String name;

    @Version
    private int version;

    public User(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

при этом получаю получаю записи из таблицы с историей так

```
 public List<User> getHistory(String id) {
        AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());

        List<Number> auditVersions = auditReader.getRevisions(User.class, id);
        List<User> users = auditVersions.stream().map(item -> auditReader.find(User.class, id, item.intValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return extractRiskMetrics(riskMetricRecords);
    }
```

Но, при записи сущностей в таблицу истории, при чтении этой истории, у всех сущностей в поле version null - это по таблице AUD, но в ней добавились новые поля REV_TYPE и REV. В Основной таблице, где хранятся последние версии сещностей - с версией все ок.

Использую spring+jpa+hibernate на сервере websphere8.5.5.13 c бд Oracle11g

Зависимости hibernate:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Пробовал найти конфликты как посоветовал @Senior Pomidor

```
mvn com.ning.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-versions-check-plugin:list
```

> INFO] --- maven-dependency-versions-check-plugin:2.0.4:list
>   (default-cli) @ SBRiskDataSvcs-webapp --- [WARNING] Missing POM for
>   com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT [WARNING] Missing POM for
>   com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js5-SNAPSHOT [INFO] Transitive
>   dependencies for scope 'compile': [INFO] antlr:antlr:
>   antlr:antlr-2.7.7 (2.7.7) [INFO] com.oracle.odb:ojdbc7:
>   com.oracle.odb:ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0 (*12.1.0.2.0*) [INFO]
>   commons-codec:commons-codec:
>   commons-codec:commons-codec-1.9 (1.9) [INFO]
>   commons-collections:commons-collections:
>   commons-collections:commons-collections-3.2.1 (3.2.1) [INFO]
>   commons-io:commons-io:
>   commons-io:commons-io-2.5 (*2.5*) [INFO]
>   commons-logging:commons-logging:
>   commons-logging:commons-logging-1.2 (1.2) [INFO] dom4j:dom4j:
>   dom4j:dom4j-1.6.1 (1.6.1) [INFO]
>   javax.activation:javax.activation-api:
>   javax.activation:javax.activation-api-1.2.0 (1.2.0) [INFO]
>   javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:
>   javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api-3.0.1 (*3.0.1*) [INFO]
>   javax.validation:validation-api:
>   javax.validation:validation-api-2.0.1.Final (*2.0.1.Final*) [INFO]
>   javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:
>   javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api-2.3.1 (*2.3.1*) [INFO]
>   org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:
>   org.apache.commons:commons-lang3-3.8.1 (*3.8.1*) [INFO]
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-4.5.1 (*4.5.1*) [INFO]
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-4.4.3 (4.4.3) [INFO]
>   org.aspectj:aspectjrt:
>   org.aspectj:aspectjrt-1.8.12 (1.8.12) [INFO]
>   org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:
>   org.aspectj:aspectjweaver-1.8.9 (1.8.9) [INFO]
>   org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:
>   org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final
>   (4.0.1.Final) [INFO]
>   org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:
>   org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
>   (1.0.1.Final) [INFO] org.hibernate:hibernate-core:
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final (4.0.1.Final) [INFO]
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final (*4.0.1.Final*)
>   [INFO] org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final (*4.0.1.Final*) [INFO]
>   org.javassist:javassist:
>   org.javassist:javassist-3.18.2-GA (3.15.0-GA, *3.18.2-GA*) [INFO]
>   org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:
>   org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2 (3.1.0.CR2) [INFO]
>   org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:
>   org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final
>   (1.0.0.Final) [INFO] org.projectlombok:lombok:
>   org.projectlombok:lombok-1.18.2 (*1.18.2*) [INFO]
>   org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:
>   org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25 (*1.7.25*) [INFO]
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-api-1.7.25 (1.7.25) [INFO]
>   org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:
>   org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE
>   (1.13.9.RELEASE) [INFO] org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:
>   org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE
>   (*1.11.9.RELEASE*) [INFO] org.springframework:spring-aop:
>   org.springframework:spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE (4.3.11.RELEASE,
>   !4.3.13.RELEASE!) [INFO] org.springframework:spring-aspects:
>   org.springframework:spring-aspects-4.3.11.RELEASE (*4.3.11.RELEASE*)
>   [INFO] org.springframework:spring-beans:
>   org.springframework:spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE (4.3.11.RELEASE,
>   !4.3.13.RELEASE!) [INFO] org.springframework:spring-context:
>   org.springframework:spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE (*4.3.11.RELEASE*,
>   !4.3.13.RELEASE!) [INFO] org.springframework:spring-core:
>   org.springframework:spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE (*4.3.11.RELEASE*,
>   !4.3.13.RELEASE!) [INFO] org.springframework:spring-expression:
>   org.springframework:spring-expression-4.3.11.RELEASE (4.3.11.RELEASE,
>   !4.3.13.RELEASE!) [INFO] org.springframework:spring-jdbc:
>   org.springframework:spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE (4.3.13.RELEASE) [INFO]
>   org.springframework:spring-orm:
>   org.springframework:spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE (4.3.13.RELEASE) [INFO]
>   org.springframework:spring-tx:
>   org.springframework:spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE (4.3.13.RELEASE) [INFO]
>   org.springframework:spring-web:
>   org.springframework:spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE (*4.3.11.RELEASE*)
>   [INFO] org.springframework:spring-webmvc:
>   org.springframework:spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE (*4.3.11.RELEASE*)
>   [INFO] xml-apis:xml-apis:
>   xml-apis:xml-apis-1.0.b2 (1.0.b2)

Comment: От количества вопросов, качество не меняется

Comment: в конфиге укажите `org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field=false`, иначе будет игнорировать @Version

Answer (score 2):

в конфиге укажите  `org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field=false`.

Этот параметр определяет, будет ли Hibernate Envers включать аннотированное поле @Version в схему аудита или нет.

Из [документации](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/envers/Envers.html)

> org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field When true,
>   properties to be used for optimistic locking, annotated with @Version,
>   will not be automatically audited (their history won’t be stored; it
>   normally doesn’t make sense to store it).

По умолчанию для этого параметра установлено значение true, что означает, что поле не подлежит автоматической проверке. хранить его историю обычно не имеет смысла.

Comment: Пробовал, но, к сожалению, не помогло

Comment: Есть подозрения, что для версии hibernate - envers 4.0.1 поле version не заполняется вовсе, вместо него появляется REV и оно просто инкрементируемое.
Но и повысить версию hibernate не могу(где все ок на сервере томкат), так как на вебсфере 8.5.5.13 появляется ошибка 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233720/javassist-123-incompatible-with-javassist-util-proxy-proxy/54236094?noredirect=1#comment95390767_54236094

Comment: попробуйте выяснить в зависимостях есть ли конфликты, например, [так](https://github.com/ning/maven-dependency-versions-check-plugin#the-list-goal)

Comment: Если все верно понял, выполнил  и не найдено конфликтов(обновил вопрос)